# How to make space in between two TextView when load in ListView adapter

Tags: android

,y `TextView` overlap another `TextView` which display time see this url https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpV7a.jpg how to add space in between two `TextView`. I'm showing this `TextView` in `ListView` adapter

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="message"
        android:id="@+id/msgDatatextview"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:textColor="#0000ff" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/msgDatatextview3"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:textColor="#0000ff" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Post your activity code, where you are setting value in text-view.

Comment: see in between report and 5 there is no space tell me how i add space in between this two textview???

Comment: Somewhere you re doing like this in activity like `textview.settext("");` post that activity code.

Comment: why do you want to use relative layout here? linearlayout will be enough

Comment: `LinearLayout` with `Horizontal` orientation is enough.

Comment: holder.msgtext.setText("" + msglist.get(position).getMsg());
 
  holder.msgtext3.setText( currenttime.substring(currenttime.length() - 5));

Answer (score 1):

try adding android:layout_toRightOf="@id/msgDatatextview" attribute to msgDatatextview3

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add line `android:layout_toRightOf="@id/msgDatatextview"` to your second TextView.

Answer (score 0):

Check your layout params, change to linear layout or check this tutorial for relative layout :
[Relative layout](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-user-interface-design-relative-layouts--mobile-4301)

I think you missed params  android:layout_toLeftOf or android:layout_toRightOf